# how to access variables in top layer class from the base class pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I have a base class and a derived class

```
class A
{
public:
int a;
}

class B : public A
{
public:
int b;
}
```

if i have a pointer of type A to a B object, how can i retrieve the pointer to the B object?

i.e.

```
A * ptrA = new B;
```

how can i use `ptrA` to access `b`?

Comment: You could downcast, but that's going to be pretty ugly. Do you *know* that `ptrA` refers to an instance of `B` (and not of some other class)? If you do, why it is a pointer to `A` and not a pointer to `B`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sure the A* is actually pointing to a B, you can do it unconditionally with no performance overhead:

```
A * ptrA = new B;
B * ptrB = static_cast<B *>(ptrA);
ptrB->b = 42;
```

This will result in undefined behavior if ptrA doesn't actually point to an instance of B.  If you aren't sure, you can check it this way:

```
if (B * ptrB = dynamic_cast<B *>(ptrA)) {
  ptrB->b = 42;
} else {
  // it's not a B, do something else
}
```

The difference here is that dynamic_cast will actually check at runtime to make sure the cast is good, and return NULL if not.

Please note that dynamic_cast will only work if your base class has at least one virtual method.  Thanks to Dietmar Kühl for pointing that out in the comments.

Comment: With his posted question, `dynamic_cast<B*>` will _not_ work because the base class has no `virtual` function at all. You can't use `dynamic_cast<B*>(ptrA)` without `virtual` functions.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: you're right, I missed that in the OP's code.  Well, thanks for pointing it out--I'll make an explicit note to see your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since your `A*` was obtained by a direct implicit conversion from `B*` you can use

```
static_cast<B*>(ptrA)->b
```

If you need to do so frequently in your code rather than just once in a blue moon, there is something wrong with your design though.

Answer (score 1):

You may cast like `(B*)ptrA->memberOfB()` in c-style cast. Or more safely: `dynamic_cast<A*>(ptrA)`.

```
ptrB = dynamic_cast<A*>(ptrA);
if(ptrB!=null)
{
    //casted properly
    ptrB->memberOfB();
}
else
{
    //can not be casted
}
```

Comment: C-style cast as no place in C++! It uses the wrong conversion (`reinterpret_cast<>()` rather than `static_cast<>()`) too easily without being visible as such.

Comment: @DietmarKühl but in practice this c-style code works, may be unsafely.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work but it is unsafe and hides easily. If nothing else the C++ casts have the strong advantage that they stick out and can be grepped for easily. Searching for C-style casts to track down suspected conversions issues is a lot harder.